# Below is my javascript for printing or saving to pdf. Its working fin on Safari, but in chrome its not

Tags: javascript, css

```js
//print function here

function print() {
  var prtContent = document.getElementById("pprint");
  var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=auto,top=auto,width=auto,height=auto,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
  WinPrint.document.write('<html><head>');
  WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('
    administration / vendor / bootstrap / css / bootstrap.min.css ')}}">');
  WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('
    administration / vendor / fontawesome / css / font - awesome.min.css ')}}">');
  WinPrint.document.write(' <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('
    administration / vendor / themify - icons / themify - icons.min.css ')}}">');
  WinPrint.document.write('<link href="{{ asset('
    administration / vendor / animate.css / animate.min.css " rel="
    stylesheet ')}}" media="screen">');
  WinPrint.document.write('    <link href="{{ asset('
    administration / vendor / perfect - scrollbar / perfect - scrollbar.min.css ') }}" rel="stylesheet"
    media = "screen" > ');
    WinPrint.document.write(' <link href="{{ asset('
      administration / vendor / switchery / switchery.min.css ') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">'); WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('
      administration / assets / css / styles.css ') }}">'); WinPrint.document.write(' <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('
      administration / assets / css / themes / theme - 1. css ') }}" id="skin_color"/>');


    WinPrint.document.write('</head><body onload="print();">'); WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML); WinPrint.document.write('</body></html>'); WinPrint.document.close(); WinPrint.focus();
  }
```

```html
images
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3J3S.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKmN2.png
```

its not printing with the correct styles and format in chrome and safari

Comment: Check what HTML it generates. Probably quotes.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get what you mean. because its generating  the html In Safari and displaying everything as it is when u convert to pdf or print. but if u try to print using chrome eish its not producing the same result

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3J3S.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKmN2.png

Comment: Check HTML generated with JS, what you write with document.write.

Comment: WinPrint.document.write('<link type="text/css" href="http://maronderardc.org.zw/administration/vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css&quot;  rel=&quot;stylesheet" media="screen">');